# Graphics drivers not working after installing VirtualBox Guest Additions

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, virtualbox

So, I'm trying out Elementary on a virtual machine before committing to it, and I've had nothing but problems along the way.

I've installed the VB Guest Additions and I've enabled 3D acceleration, but when I try to enable the graphics drivers I'm met with this:

[image: Yes that's the actual size]

No guide I've found has helped me, as most of them just say "install the guest additions and restart the vm", which hasn't helped me at all.

VM Specs:

- Elementary OS 0.3.1 x64
- VirtualBox 5.0.10
- 2 GB RAM

Host Specs (if these matter at all):

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Intel i7-3770
- nVidia GeForce GTX 680

**Output of `lsmod | grep vbox`**

```
vboxsf                45056  0
vboxvideo             16384  0
vboxguest            249856  2 vboxsf
drm                  344064  2 vboxvideo
```

**Output of `sudo lspci -v`**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
    Flags: fast devsel

00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64
    [virtual] Memory at 000001f0 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
    [virtual] Memory at 000003f0 (type 3, non-prefetchable)
    [virtual] Memory at 00000170 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
    [virtual] Memory at 00000370 (type 3, non-prefetchable)
    I/O ports at d000 [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]

00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at d010 [size=8]
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [e4] PCI-X non-bridge device
    Kernel driver in use: e1000

00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at d020 [size=32]
    Memory at f0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at f0800000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Kernel driver in use: vboxguest

00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0177
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at d100 [size=256]
    I/O ports at d200 [size=64]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0

00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 22
    Memory at f0804000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 9

00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at d240 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0000
    I/O ports at d250 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0000
    I/O ports at d260 [size=16]
    Memory at f0806000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `lsmod | grep vbox` and `sudo lspci -v` run inside the vbox machine?

Comment: @Sneetsher done.

Comment: Elementary is very stable and nice looking on my laptop.Haven't tried it on a VM but I recommend you install it

Comment: @SuiciDoga nearly all the packages I use in daily development are outdated in elementary, which isn't very useful for me at all

Comment: Ok @ElectricCoffee so it will be too unstable

Comment: first let me ask why do you want 3d acceleration on in an VM? because you cannot test gaming in a vm. you cannot test any programming opencl, opengl or parallelism in a vm. It all needs native hardware control. beside virtual box doesn't has a great graphic driver. 

if you want to test elementary i would suggest doing a live boot session and test all you want.  flash a bootable usb pendrive. boot from the usb pendrive and select try out instead of install.

about the packages we use ubuntu LTS so it is known to be a bit outdated. but what libs or packages do you use for development?

Comment: @kay so I can run it in full screen and have two operating systems running seamlessly at the same time

Comment: If you just want to have full screen you only need a fresh installed VM and install virtual box guest aditions.  once this is done it normally goes to full screen but some times you need to select in the taskbar for full screen
no 3d and no 2d acceleration is needed just turn them of.

unless if you want to do any gaming, video and photo editing you need to use live usb. VM don't support these applications to work good.

Comment: @kay none of that worked, which is why I posted this question in the first place

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.